# unity3d android get keyhash runtime

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, apk

I am currently developing a game on Unity3d. To my best knowledge, I know that if you somehow tamper the apk file its signature is changed. Now is there any way to get the current signature of the apk so that I can match it against a saved one and detect if any alteration is made with my apk.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check in Java it like this

```
public static boolean checkSignature(Context context,String keyToCheck) {
        try {
            PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
            PackageInfo pi = pm.getPackageInfo(<your package name>, PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
            for (Signature sig : pi.signatures) {
                MessageDigest sha = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
                sha.update(sig.toByteArray());
                byte[] digest = sha.digest();
                String str = "";
                for (int di = 0; di < digest.length; di++) {
                    str += Byte.toString(digest[di]) + ":";
                }
                if (str.equals(keyToCheck)) {
                    return true;
                }
            } 
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
      return false;
    }
```

keyToCheck has this format "-111:-31:91:-71:51:-11:71:6:-41:9:-91:71:6:81:3:41:21:-81:11:-1:";

Comment: How can we use this plugin on Unity C# side ? the checkSignature method has 2 arguments. can you explain please ? @aelimill